# Can't install terminal plugin of gedit

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gedit, plugins

I was trying to embed terminal to gedit. But **Embedded Terminal** option is missing when I go to **Edit** -> **Preference**->**Plugin**. On searching web I figured that I need to install `gedit-plugin` which I can find on Ubuntu Software Store. But when I searched `gedit-plugin` it says "No Application Found". Am I missing something, or doing something wrong? Please guide me through, I am new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The exact name of the package is `gedit-plugins`, not <s>`gedit-plugin`</s> ([check here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gedit-plugins)). To install this, you'd use the command

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```